# How to sort by field order ACF Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'd like to display my field group as is in the front-end.

[image: My Field Group]

and I'm currently using this code:

```
$fields = get_field_objects();

if( $fields )
{
    foreach( $fields as $field_name => $field )
    {
        echo '<div>';
            echo '<h3>' . $field['label'] . '</h3>';
            echo $field['value'];
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

also how to get the field name of an ACF TAB?

Answer (score 0):

I found out about `order_no` field in every array of field in ACF. So I tried to usort.

```
usort($fields, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['order_no'] - $b['order_no'];
});
```